# Session variables not carrying over

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to write a log in script that will set a session variable and then redirect the user to another page.  The session variables displays fine on the page where it's set, but on the next page it does not display at all.  I have stripped down my home page so that all it does is echo the session variable.

login.php:

```
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['process_login'])){
            include('php/db.php');

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT USERS.USERNAME, USERS.PASSWORD FROM USERS") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    if (strtoupper($_POST['username']) != $result['USERNAME'] || md5($_POST['password']) != $result['PASSWORD']){

                            echo "<center><font color=red>Incorrect username or password</font><center>";
                    }
                    else{
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                            #echo $_SESSION['username'];
                            #printr ($_SESSION);
                            echo "<script> window.location = \"home.php\"; </script>";
                    }
                    //echo $result['username'];
            }
    }
```

home.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: Yes.  I tried it on Windows, OSX, and iOS with Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.  Doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: I thougt sessions work without cookies as well?

Comment: Have you tried passing the session id variable to see if it is a cookie issue?

Answer (score -1):

The way you've got it set up it should work fine.. Is that all the code you have?

Comment: For home.php that is all that is in it right now.  Here's my entire login.php. http://pastebin.com/Z5qTpnzN

Comment: This could be a comment :)

Comment: By the way: session_start(); has to be the first statement in your code! Put in on line 1 ! And also try to put an error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of your code to identify more errors.

Comment: @T_01, no it has to be before  any output, NOT the first thing n your code.

Comment: Yes i know, but to prevent any errors, its betterto have it on the top ;)

Comment: @Dagon Thank you so much!  I move session_start() to the top of login.php and it works fine now!